# How to find the branch number using git

Tags: git, github

In Git, there is a command `git checkout ***`, I am wondering how to get the number to checkout?

Comment: Use `gitk` or `git log` to see your history.

Comment: By the way, I really recommend reading [ProGit](http://git-scm.com/book)

Answer (score 0):

`git log` will show you the commit history for your respository, which will include the SHA1 identifier for each commit, like this:

```
commit 7fd1a60b01f91b314f59955a4e4d4e80d8edf11d
Merge: 553c207 7629413
Author: The Octocat <octocat@nowhere.com>
Date:   Tue Mar 6 15:06:50 2012 -0800

    Merge pull request #6 from Spaceghost/patch-1

    New line at end of file.

commit 762941318ee16e59dabbacb1b4049eec22f0d303
Author: Johnneylee Jack Rollins <Johnneylee.rollins@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 13 21:42:41 2011 -0700

    New line at end of file. --Signed off by Spaceghost
```

You can check out a particular commit like this:

```
git checkout 762941318ee16e59dabbacb1b4049eec22f0d303
```

...but this isn't often what you want to do, because this puts you in a "detached HEAD" state in which any new commits you make will not be reachable from any branch, meaning that they will ultimately be removed by the garbage collection mechanism.  This is a great way to lose data.

What often makes more sense is to create a new branch based on this commit:

```
git checkout -b mybranch 762941318ee16e59dabbacb1b4049eec22f0d303
```

Now you're on a new branch called `mybranch` and any new commits you make will work as expected.  You can switch back to your `master` branch like this:

```
git checkout master
```

Also, sinelaw's suggestion about [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book) was an excellent one.

Answer (score 0):

```
git describe
git describe --tags
```

without --tags argument, it only considers non-annotated tags.
add --tags argument to consider non-annotated tags

may give the relative revision number based on previous tag
for example, there is a tag v2.0.0.
your current commit is 12 commits after commit tagged v2.0.0.
then the output is v2.0.0-12-g1234abc, where 12 is the relative revision number